# Can we use python 2.7 in pyxpcomext?

Tags: firefox-addon, python-2.7, mozilla

I want to develop mozilla extension using python 2.7 or higher. And i know
that they having 2.5.2 in their extension(i.e. pyxpcomext).
I already googled the question but couldnt find anything.

Comment: [`pythonext` 6.0.0](http://code.google.com/p/pythonext/) uses Python 2.6.

Comment: Yes, it uses Python 2.6 - and it has only been updated for Firefox 10 which is pretty old by now (latest download works even with Firefox 6 only). Why do you want to build on a binary XPCOM component that needs to be updated for every single Firefox release? You should just use JavaScript and save yourself the trouble.